# Assign default selection from dropdown to model class within another model

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js, webforms

Here is some of the relevant code right away

### Markup

```
<div class="well">
    <input type="button" id="addNewCert" value="Add New Certification" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addCert"/>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: certs">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#editCert" data-bind="click: $parent.editCert">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="#deleteCert" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCert">Delete</a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certCode"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certType.certTypeName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <div id="selectedCert" data-bind="with: selectedCert">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h6>Certification Name</h6>
                            <input type="text" id="CertificationName" data-bind="value: certName" style="width:100%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h6>Certification Code</h6>
                            <input type="text" id="CertificationCode" data-bind="value: certCode" style="width:50%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h6>Description</h6>
                            <textarea ID="Description" data-bind="value: description" style="height:250px;width:480px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <h6>Certification Type</h6>
                            <select id="CertificationType" data-bind="options: $parent.availableCertTypes, optionsText: 'certTypeName', optionsValue: 'certTypeId', value: $parent.selectedCertType" style="width:100%;"></select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.save">Save</button>
                            <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $parent.cancel">Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### ViewModel

```
//Bound to a dropdown and populated by an ajax call listed below
self.availableCertTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedCert = ko.observable();

self.addCert = function () {
    self.selectedCert(new Certification({});

    //This line doesn't work :( 
    //self.selectedCert(new Certification(self.availableCertTypes()[0]));

};

//Populates availableCertTypes
    $.getJSON(sf.getServiceRoot('InCertModule') + 'InCert/GetCertTypesByPortal', function (data) {
        //Could call 'self.Certs(self.MapItems(data))' here as that would take the fetched data and populate the viewModel's list of certifications used for binding

        var mappedCertTypes = $.map(data, function (item) {
            return new CertType(item);
        });

        self.availableCertTypes(mappedCertTypes);
    });
```

### Models

```
var Certification = function (data) {
    if (!data) {
        //If there is no data, pass an empty intialized object, otherwise get an undefined reference
        data = {};
    } else {

        this.certId = ko.observable(data.CertificationId);
        this.certName = ko.observable(data.CertificationName);
        this.certCode = ko.observable(data.CertificationCode);
        this.description = ko.observable(data.Description);
        this.certType = ko.observable(new CertType(data));
        //this.certTypeId = ko.observable(data.CertTypeId);
        //this.certTypeName = ko.observable(data.CertTypeName);
        this.isEditing = ko.observable(false);
        this.isValid = ko.observable(true);
    }
}

var CertType = function (data) {
    this.certTypeId = ko.observable(data.CertTypeId);
    this.certTypeName = ko.observable(data.CertTypeName);
}
```

I also have an edit function set up with a `with` binding. This works correctly and gets my CertType model nested properly, like so

```
  "selectedCert": {
    "certId": 10,
    "certName": "AFC Service Training",
    "certCode": "AFCST",
    "description": "The training required to work AFC service",
    "certType": {
      "certTypeId": 1,
      "certTypeName": "Certification"
    },
    "isEditing": false,
    "isValid": true
  },
```

However, I've tried a few combinations for my `addCert` function to take the very first item in the `availableCertTypes` ObservableArray and assign it. Reason being is when I post it to my web service, I need to ensure that something is selected there.

I'm new to Knockout.js so not even sure what's possible or how to really accomplish it but ideally when I call `addCert`, I'd like to see something similar to this

```
"selectedCert": {
    //The first item in the observable array 
    "certType": {
      "certTypeId": 1,
      "certTypeName": "Certification"
    },
    "isEditing": false,
    "isValid": true
  }
```

but instead I wind up with

```
"selectedCert": {
    "certType": {},
    "isEditing": false,
    "isValid": true
  }
```

If I need to post more code I can, just let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Here is a jsFiddle with most of the markup, although it's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/jtCrw/1/

The array binds correctly when fetched from the web service, just not sure how to hard code those in there. Currently those 2 are the only two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your empty `certType` problem is due to a mismatch/typo in your setup.

```
 self.addCert = function () {
   self.selectedCert(new Certification(self.availableCertTypes()[0]));
 }
```

resulting in an eventual call to `this.certType = ko.observable(new CertType(data));`

```
 var CertType = function (data) {
   this.certTypeId = ko.observable(data.CertTypeId); //expecting uppercase property
   this.certTypeName = ko.observable(data.CertTypeName);
 }

self.availableCertTypes = ko.observableArray([
        {
          "certTypeId": 1, //data-bind and this declaration are both lowercase               
          "certTypeName": "Certification"
        },
        {
          "certTypeId": 2,
          "certTypeName": "Training"
        }
    ]);
```

fixing that yields the expected result from your current setup

```
"selectedCertType":{"CertTypeId":1,"CertTypeName":"Certification"}
```

---

To get the desired outcome as you have shown/requested, remove the `optionsValue` from the select binding and bind the `value` to the `certType` of the selected certification (provided by the `with` binding)

```
 <select id="CertificationType" 
         data-bind="options: $parent.availableCertTypes, 
                    optionsText: 'CertTypeName', 
                    value: certType"
         style="width:100%;"></select>
```

Result:

```
 "selectedCert":{"certType":{"CertTypeId":1,"CertTypeName":"Certification"},"isEditing":false,"isValid":true}
```

---

**Consideration**: If you want to populate the select with data from an existing certification, some special consideration is needed. Take a look at [examples of initialization](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/2RmCJ/).

Comment: That worked nicely. Is there a different assignment that I can use besides nesting `new Certification(CertType(item[index])` that might make things a little easier?

I feel like the way I have it now is just making things harder on myself. I'd like to learn somewhat best practice since I am just learning.

Comment: It depends on how much information you need to hold onto for other activities. There is no inherent problem with nesting the models, you just have to be aware of the extra complexity that involves. What you have now made sense to me based on the context I could gather from the fiddle. If you don't need the `certType` object for anything else, flatten it out inside of the `Certification` to just be the id property and revert the data-bind back to using `optionsValue: 'CertTypeId'` that way you only store the simple property of id rather than a full object.

Comment: Considering it's a rather simple object I may just go for flattening the object out instead of nesting it.